# Transparent UIView on top detecting touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer, transparent

I have an iPad project structured with a UISplitViewController:

- RootViewController
- DetailviewController

Both of them are detecting touches with Gesture Recognizer inside their own Class.

I would like to create a transparent **UIView on top of all the Classes** to detect ONLY a Diagonal Swipe (from the left bottom corner to the right top corner).

So, when the swipe will be detected I will launch a function **otherwise** nothing appended and the touch should be passed on the low level view.

I tried these two solutions:

- Add a GestureRecognizer on this top transparent view but this will hide all touches to the lower hierarchy views.( with userInteraction enabled: YES ofcourse);

The other solution is to make the init like this

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.01]];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
 }

 return self;
```

}

and try to detect the swipe with

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But at this point all the touches are not detected.

Anybody have a nice solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not create a transparent UIView like you are mentioning. I will add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the `UISplitViewController`'s view this is already the view that contains all your subviews. You can have access to the view within the `app` delegate:

```
 UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 // attach the swipe gesture to the view that embeds the rootView and the detailView
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:splitViewController.view action:@selector(swipeUpdated:)];
```

Comment: Tnx @tiguero for the quick answer.You are right but not all the IOS versions support the Gesture recognizer. What i found out is that the correct way should be to **subclassing** the UIWindow and override the `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and the `-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.So i can call/or not call the `[super sendEvent:event]` to pass or not the event into the UIViews Hierarchy. What do u think guys about this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add a gesture recognizer to the `UISplitViewController`'s view?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `Container Controllers`. You can make your own `SplitViewController` and make a third view on top of the controller that detects the swipe. Custom container controllers are pretty straight forward and gives you a lot of flexibility.